# ReactJS - How to deploy the build folder with the proper paths being referenced?

Tags: reactjs

I've just run "npm run build" on a react app built with the create-react-app npm package. The issue now is that all the minified and bundled files and folders are referencing the root folder, when they are in a sub-folder. I've tried changing  in index.html but that doesn't seem to work. Help?

Comment: I suggest you can refer to the webpack's configuration . That would help you.

Comment: Please share your webpack configuration, it is probably the `publicPath` is not set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

@Jason Xu and @Mamdoh Saraireh thank you so very much for responding and attempting to help me.

It seems I am a complete idiot and did not read the full output of the build message. The solution to my problem is to add

```
"hompage":"./"
```

into my package.json file before running npm run build